# Resume mediaplayer after paused

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-viewpager, android-mediaplayer

Used ViewPager for images sliding, when clicking on each image must stream mp3, its different mp3 from image to another (all mp3 stored on app itself, app including 50 pages(images) & 50 mp3).

when I click the image the audio stream Correctly , if I click again its stop the mp3 then the third click it restart the mp3 from the beginning,

**I want the third click to resume the mp3 from position where it paused .**

MainActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private ViewPager mViewPager;
 MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     mViewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
     ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
     mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

     final GestureDetector tapGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new TapGestureListener());
     mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             tapGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
             return false;
         }
     });
 }

 private class TapGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
     @Override
   public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

      if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {

            if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
               mp.pause();

              }else{

               mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.aa);                  
               mp.start();

                  }
               }    
      else if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {

            if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
               mp.pause();


             }else{

              mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bb);
              mp.start();

                   }
               }
     else if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {

           if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
              mp.pause();

             }else{

             mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.cc);
             mp.start();
                }
            }
    else if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 3) {                  

          if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
             mp.pause();

             }else{

             mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.dd);
             mp.start();
                }
           }
   else if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 4) {                  

         if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.pause();

            }else{

           mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ee);
           mp.start();
                }
         } else if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 5) {                  

             if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
                 mp.pause();

              }else{

           mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ff);
           mp.start();
                }
         }
  else if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 6) {

             if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
                 mp.pause();

              }else{

           mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.gg);
           mp.start();
                }           
         }

         return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
         }
     } 
 }
```

please any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can manage the three times click on same image correctly as below:

1-First click ==) play MP3.

1-Second click ==) pause mp3

3-Third click ==) resume playing again the mp3 from where it paused .

```
 if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
          if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
              mp.pause();
           length = mp.getCurrentPosition();

             }else{

             mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.aa);
             mp.seekTo(length);

             mp.start();
             }             

          }
```